# Select nested collection's property in select clause

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I am using System.Linq.Dynamic, version on [github's repository](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic).

I am NOT interested in NON System.Linq.Dynamic solution.

I am trying to perform select on nested collection's property. Let us imagine we have following situation:

```
public class Region
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public List<Town> Towns { get; set; }
}
public class Town
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Would it be possible to 'Select' region's id and it's town's names?
Something of a kind:

```
someListofRegions.Select("new(Id, Towns.Name)")
```

where `"new(Id, Towns.Name)"` is the dynamic Linq expression.

of course example above fails.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?. I'm in the same situation

Answer (score -1):

You can't perform a select on a nested collection's property as this would require flattening of the resulting collection.

Usually you would use SelectMany() to do this flattening, but since you want to use System.Linq.Dynamic and I don't believe this library has a dynamic SelectMany() this probably isn't possible.  You could write your own SelectMany() though using expression trees which shouldn't be too difficult.

Alternatively you may find GroupBy is more suited to your needs here anyway, I can't personally see the benefit in wanting a collection of Region IDs and Town Names - there would be loads of duplicate region IDs.

Comment: There is no need for SelectMany, you could write just Select(region => new { region.Id, region.Towns.Select(t => t.Name)) - but that is without 'dynamic' bits

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but the code you wrote there would return a collection of anonymous types similar to that returned by GroupBy().  It would NOT return a flattened list of Region IDs and Town Names which is what I believe he was asking for in the question.

This is why i suggested that maybe he needed a GroupBy() instead of a Select()